# Smooth 'turning' script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, radians

I am making an HTML5 Canvas game using Javascript.

I want to make an object turn smoothly to a certain direction.

I am storing the direction as a variable, and using radians. The code works like this:

```js
window.setInterval(loop,25);

var dir = 0;
var targetDir = Math.PI/2;

function loop() {
  dir += (targetDir - dir) / 5;
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = dir; //To display the direction
}
```

```html
<p id='text'></p>
```

It will work most of the time, but if the direction and target direction are on opposite left/right sides, the computer will assume the fastest way to get to the target is to to all the way around, like this:
[(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W79vW.png)

Does anyone know an algorithm I can use to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hoping someone would answer with an elegant solution, nothing yet so here is how I do it.

I have always found the solution to this problem very inelegant, that said, I do not know if there is a better way, nor have i endeavored to find one. Below are two functions that will return the shortest direction between two angles that derived from the function `Math.atan2(yDif, xDif)` which returns an angle in the range -`Math.PI` to `Math.PI`

Get shortest direction.

```
// returns true if shortest direction is clockwise else false
function isShortestDirClockwise(ang1, ang2){
    if (ang1 < 0) {
        if ( (ang2 < 0 && ang1 > ang2) || (ang2 >= 0 && ang1 + Math.PI < ang2) ) {
            return false;        
        }
    } else {
        if ( (ang2 > 0 && ang1 > ang2) || (ang2 <= 0 && ang1 - Math.PI < ang2) ) {
            return false;        
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Get shortest angle

```
// returns the shortest angle neg angles are counterClockwise positive are clockwise
function getShortestAngle(ang1, ang2){
    var cw = true; // clockwise
    var ang;
    if (ang1 < 0) {
        if( (ang2 < 0 && ang1 > ang2) || (ang2 >= 0 && ang1 + Math.PI < ang2) ) {
            cw = false;        
        }
    } else {
        if ( (ang2 > 0 && ang1 > ang2) || (ang2 <= 0 && ang1 - Math.PI < ang2) ) {
            cw = false;        
        }
    }
    if (cw) {
        var ang = ang2 - ang1;
        if (ang < 0) {
            ang = ang2 + Math.PI * 2 - ang1;
        }
        return ang;
    }
    var ang = ang1 - ang2;
    if (ang < 0) {
        ang = ang1 + Math.PI * 2 - ang2;
    }   
    return -ang;
}
```

As I loath using these functions I much prefer the slightly more complex yet more elegant solution below. This finds the shortest angle in terms of a set of 3 points. the center point, and the two points that I wish to find the angle between and it always returns the shortest angle between any two lines.

```
 // Warning may return NAN if there is no solution (ie one or both points (p1,p2) are at center)
 // Also uses Math.hypot check browser compatibility if you wish to use this function or use Math.sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y) instead
 function getAngleBetween(center, p1, p2){
     var d;
     var ang;
     // get vectors from center to both points
     var v1 = { x : p1.x - center.x, y : p1.y - center.y};
     var v2 = { x : p2.x - center.x, y : p2.y - center.y};
     // normalise both vectors
     d = Math.hypot(v1.x, v1.y);
     v1.x /= d;
     v1.y /= d;
     d = Math.hypot(v2.x, v2.y);
     v2.x /= d;
     v2.y /= d;
     // cross product gets the angle in range -Math.PI / 2 to Math.PI / 2
     ang = Math.asin(v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x);
     // use the cross product of the line perpendicular to the first to find the quadrant
     if(-v1.y * v2.y - v1.x * v2.x > 0){
         if(ang < 0){
            ang = -Math.PI - ang;
         }else{
            ang = Math.PI - ang;
         }
     }
     return ang;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to keep the question 'unanswered', though, just in case someone has that 'elegant solution' you were talking about.